# How to display included files in multiple navigation pages

Tags: php, laravel-5, bootstrap-4

I intend to display a jumbotron in multiple pages of my application, I have been able to display it on the home page, how do I replicate such on other pages.

I'm using Laravel 5.8 and Bootstrap 4 .It displayed on the default home page`('/')`, I have tried replacing `('/')` 
 with the page name in the route file which is `'training'` (from `...->name('training')`) i.e but it didn't display. I have also tried replacing it with `'/Training'` and `'pages/training'` but it still didn't work.

The code in the master blade file (resources/views/layout/app.blade.php) is;

```
@if (Request::is('training'))
     @include('inc.showcase')
@endif
```

The code for the showcase file (resources/views/inc/showcase.blade.php) is;

```
<div class="jumbotron text-center">
    <div class="container">
        <p>Welcome to My Page</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

The code for the child blade (resources/views/pages/training.blade.php) is;

```
@extends('layout.app')

@section('content')
    <h1>Training</h1>
@endsection
```

That of the route file (routes\web.php) is;

```
Route::get('/Training', 'PageController@getTraining')->name('training');
```

And that of the controller (app\Http\Controllers\PageController.php) is;

```
public function getTraining(){
        return view('pages/training');
    }
```

I expect the Jumbotron to display in the training page but nothing displays at all, except for the home page when i use `(/)`

Comment: Have you considered using a different layout that contains the jumbotron? Pages that want/need to have a jumbotron can easily just `@extend` this new layout file without you having to manually add more and more `@if (Request::is('XYZ'))` for every new page

Comment: I have done it and it works fine. Thanks

Comment: Not a problem, glad it works